# Problem with smtp configure

Tags: magento2, email, sales-order, order-email

I have magento 2.2.4 with a smtp server configured. I can send email test from the tool and i receive it correctly. But when i buy a product I do not receive any email.

What can be the error?

I have all activated on Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email. it's all activated..

Comment: you need to activate / check crons are running .  **crontab -l** into your directory and see if you have cron paths there .

Comment: i did that on my path root from Magento and this is the message <No crontab for bitnami> but i have all the crontabs activated on Magento backend

Comment: I fixed it, The problem was on Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email: The option Asynchronous sending was Enabled but must be Disable

Comment: Glad you fixed it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email: The option Asynchronous Sending
```

This option just sends it over the cronjobs if enabled.
If you disable this it will send emails instantly.

If you find yourself in the situation that you do not receive mails if enabled --> Your crontab on your server is not configured correctly

More information about that : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html